# RegEx to extract all matches from string using RegExp.exec

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, taskwarrior

I'm trying to parse the following kind of string:

```
[key:"val" key2:"val2"]
```

where there are arbitrary key:"val" pairs inside. I want to grab the key name and the value. 
For those curious I'm trying to parse the database format of task warrior.

Here is my test string:

```
[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]
```

which is meant to highlight that anything can be in a key or value aside from space, no spaces around the colons, and values are always in double quotes.

In node, this is my output:

```
[deuteronomy][gatlin][~]$ node
> var re = /^\[(?:(.+?):"(.+?)"\s*)+\]$/g
> re.exec('[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]');
[ '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]',
  'uuid',
  '123sth',
  index: 0,
  input: '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]' ]
```

But `description:"aoeu"` also matches this pattern. How can I get all matches back?

Comment: It might be that my regex is wrong and / or that I am simply using the regex facilities in JavaScript incorrectly. This seems to work:     > var s = "Fifteen is 15 and eight is 8"; > var re = /\d+/g; > var m = s.match(re); m = [ '15', '8' ]

Comment: Javascript now has a .match() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Used like this: `"some string".match(/regex/g)`

Comment: You can now iterate on `str.matchAll(regex)` to get all matches, including meta-info like groups. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573169) should be the accepted answer, since it's quite well-supported now.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Continue calling `re.exec(s)` in a loop to obtain all the matches:

```
var re = /\s*([^[:]+):\"([^"]+)"/g;
var s = '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1], m[2]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Try it with this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yS2V/

Comment: Why not `while` instead of `do … while`?

Comment: Using a while loop makes it slightly awkward to initialize m. You either have to write `while(m = re.exec(s))`, which is an anti-pattern IMO, or you have to write `m = re.exec(s); while (m) { ... m = re.exec(s); }`. I prefer the `do ... if ... while` idiom, but other techniques would work as well.

Comment: doing this in chromium resulted in my tab crashing.

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg You need to have the `g` flag set, otherwise the internal pointer is not moved forward. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Comment: @lawnsea How about a for loop?

Comment: Also, the regex should be in a variable to make the pointer increment it's position. having a runtime regex would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Can't you just have the loop be `while(m = re.exec(a)) { console.log(m[1], m[2]); }` ?

Comment: Another point is that if the regex can match empty string it will be an infinite loop

Comment: @lawnsea please update your answer to: `let m; while (m = re.exec(s)) { console.log(m[1], m[2]); }`

Comment: @FabioCosta Just encountered the issue with infinite loop. It's so frustrating that to avoid this bug everyone should manually check the equality of current and previous matches, and, if they are the same, increment `RegExp`s `lastIndex`. The answer should be definitely updated with this information. It's good that the new `matchAll` method for strings does this check by itself, and now we can refuse to use loops at all (thank @iuliu.net for the information). The last unpleasant point is that `RegExp`s contain state and thus should be copied manually to avoid undesirable
 mutations.

Answer (score 251):

`str.match(pattern)`, if `pattern` has the global flag `g`, will return all the matches as an array.

For example:

```js
const str = 'All of us except @Emran, @Raju and @Noman were there';
console.log(
  str.match(/@\w*/g)
);
// Will log ["@Emran", "@Raju", "@Noman"]
```

Comment: Beware: the matches aren't match objects, but the matching strings. For example, there is no access to the groups in `"All of us except @Emran:emran26, @Raju:raju13 and @Noman:noman42".match(/@(\w+):(\w+)/g)` (which will return `["@Emran:emran26", "@Raju:raju13", "@Noman:noman42"]`)

Comment: @madprog, Right, it's the easiest way but not suitable when the group values are essential.

Comment: This isn't working for me.   I only get the first match.

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts you must add the "g" flag. `/@\w/g` or `new RegExp("@\\w", "g")`

Answer (score 101):

To loop through all matches, you can use the `replace` function:

```
var re = /\s*([^[:]+):\"([^"]+)"/g;
var s = '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]';

s.replace(re, function(match, g1, g2) { console.log(g1, g2); });
```

Comment: I think it is just too complicated. However, it is nice to know about different ways of doing a simple thing (I up-vote your answer).

Comment: It's counterintuitive code. You're not “replacing” anything in any meaningful sense. It's just exploiting the some function for a different purpose.

Comment: @LukeMaurer is right. This is using a facility of Javascript intended for _string replacement_ to perform a _string search_. Sure, it's simpler, but did NASA slingshot the New Horizons around Pluto by taking the "simple" route, or by taking the "correct" route? We're engineers and should respect that doing it the easy way is not always right. Shying away from learning regex because it's hard is simply lazy programming. I don't mean to be derisive, rather, honest. This manifests in important ways when other developers waste half an hour trying to figure out what line three of this example does.

Comment: @dudewad if engineers were just following the rules without thinking outside of the box, we would not even be thinking about visiting other planets right now ;-)

Comment: Yes but this isn't creative thinking, it's lazy thinking. You can tell when there's a better solution, and this is one of those times.

Comment: @dudewad sorry, I fail to see the lazy part here. If the exact same method was called "process" instead of "replace" you would be ok with it. I am afraid you're just stuck on the terminology.

Comment: @Christophe I am definitely not stuck on terminology. I'm stuck on clean code. Using things that are intended for one purpose for a different purpose is called "hacky" for a reason. It creates confusing code that is difficult to understand and more often than not suffers performance-wise. The fact that you answered this question without a regex in and of itself makes it an invalid answer, since the OP is asking for how to do it with regex. I find it important, however, to hold this community to a high standard, which is why I stand by what I said above.

Comment: @dudewad what do you mean, without a regex?

Comment: Sry -- to clarify that, I mean by not doing it on a regex object, rather you're using an additional layer instead of using the regex itself.

Comment: @dudewad okay. How does that make it an invalid answer? I am fine with you not agreeing, even downvoting, but let's do it in good faith.

Comment: Some people wouldn't climb on a table to change a light bulb cuz tables are for eating on. They would only use a ladder certified for lightbulb-changing. Anything else is "hacky" and not a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 61):

This is a solution

```
var s = '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]';

var re = /\s*([^[:]+):\"([^"]+)"/g;
var m;
while (m = re.exec(s)) {
  console.log(m[1], m[2]);
}
```

This is based on lawnsea's answer, but shorter.

Notice that the `g' flag must be set to move the internal pointer forward across invocations.

Answer (score 36):

```
str.match(/regex/g)
```

returns all matches as an array.

If, for some mysterious reason, you need the additional information comes with `exec`, as an alternative to previous answers, you could do it with a recursive function instead of a loop as follows (which also looks cooler :).

```
function findMatches(regex, str, matches = []) {
   const res = regex.exec(str)
   res && matches.push(res) && findMatches(regex, str, matches)
   return matches
}

// Usage
const matches = findMatches(/regex/g, str)
```

as stated in the comments before, it's important to have `g` at the end of regex definition to move the pointer forward in each execution.

Comment: yes. recursive looks elegant and cooler. Iterative loops are straight forward, easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: I love recursive solutions because; I love recursive solutions

Comment: What is the limit for nodejs for recursion depth? Could 1_000_000 matches lead to stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 29):

We are finally beginning to see a built-in `matchAll` function, see [here for the description and compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll). It looks like as of May 2020, Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Node.js (12+) are supported but not IE, Safari, and Opera. Seems like it was [drafted in December 2018](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-string-matchall/#sec-string-prototype-matchall) so give it some time to reach all browsers, but I trust it will get there.

The built-in `matchAll` function is nice because it returns an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). It also returns capturing groups for every match! So you can do things like

```js
// get the letters before and after "o"
let matches = "stackoverflow".matchAll(/(\w)o(\w)/g);

for (match of matches) {
    console.log("letter before:" + match[1]);
    console.log("letter after:" + match[2]);
}

arrayOfAllMatches = [...matches]; // you can also turn the iterable into an array
```

It also seem like every match object uses the same format as [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). So each object is an array of the match and capturing groups, along with three additional properties `index`, `input`, and `groups`. So it looks like:

```
[<match>, <group1>, <group2>, ..., index: <match offset>, input: <original string>, groups: <named capture groups>]
```

For more information about `matchAll` there is also a [Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/string-matchall). There are also [polyfills/shims](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-matchall#polyfillshim) available.

Comment: I really like this, but it hasn't quite landed in Firefox 66.0.3 yet. [Caniuse](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4845) doesn't have a support list about it yet either. I'm looking forward to this one. I do see it working in Chromium 74.0.3729.108.

Comment: @LonnieBest yeah you can see the compatibility section of the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) that I linked. It seems like Firefox started supporting it in version 67. Still would not recommend using it if you're trying to ship a product. There are polyfills/shims available, which I added to my answer

Answer (score 18):

## If you have ES9

(Meaning if your system: Chrome, Node.js, Firefox, etc supports Ecmascript 2019 or later)

```js
yourString.matchAll( /your-regex/g ) // dont forget the "g"
```

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

## If you use NPM

You can use the official polyfill
`npm install string.prototype.matchall`

```js
const matchAll = require('string.prototype.matchall')
console.log( [...  matchAll('blah1 blah2',/blah/g)  ] )
//[
//  [ 'blah', index: 0, input: 'blah1 blah2', groups: undefined ],
//  [ 'blah', index: 6, input: 'blah1 blah2', groups: undefined ]
//]
```

## Otherwise

Here's some functionally similar copy-paste versions

```js
// returns an array, works on super old javascript (ES3 -- 1999)
function findAll(regexPattern, sourceString) {
    var output = []
    var match
    // auto-add global flag while keeping others as-is
    var regexPatternWithGlobal = regexPattern.global ? regexPattern : RegExp(regexPattern, regexPattern.flags+"g")
    while (match = regexPatternWithGlobal.exec(sourceString)) {
        // store the match data
        output.push(match)
        // zero-length matches will end up in an infinite loop, so increment by one char after a zero-length match is found
        if (match[0].length == 0) {
            regexPatternWithGlobal.lastIndex += 1
        }
    }
    return output
}

// this version returns an iterator, which is good for large results
// note: iterators require ES6 - 2015 standard
function* findAll(regexPattern, sourceString) {
    var match
    // auto-add global flag while keeping others as-is
    const regexPatternWithGlobal = regexPattern.global ? regexPattern : RegExp(regexPattern, regexPattern.flags+"g")
    while (match = regexPatternWithGlobal.exec(sourceString)) {
        // store the match data
        yield match
        // zero-length matches will end up in an infinite loop, so increment by one char after a zero-length match is found
        if (match[0].length == 0) {
            regexPatternWithGlobal.lastIndex += 1
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

example usage:

```
console.log(   findAll(/blah/g,'blah1 blah2')   )
```

outputs:

```
[ [ 'blah', index: 0 ], [ 'blah', index: 6 ] ]
```

Comment: With most of browsers supporting `str.matchAll`  this answer should be in top list

Answer (score 11):

Based on Agus's function, but I prefer return just the match values:

```
var bob = "&gt; bob &lt;";
function matchAll(str, regex) {
    var res = [];
    var m;
    if (regex.global) {
        while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
            res.push(m[1]);
        }
    } else {
        if (m = regex.exec(str)) {
            res.push(m[1]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
var Amatch = matchAll(bob, /(&.*?;)/g);
console.log(Amatch);  // yeilds: [&gt;, &lt;]
```

Answer (score 8):

Iterables are nicer:

```
const matches = (text, pattern) => ({
  [Symbol.iterator]: function * () {
    const clone = new RegExp(pattern.source, pattern.flags);
    let match = null;
    do {
      match = clone.exec(text);
      if (match) {
        yield match;
      }
    } while (match);
  }
});
```

Usage in a loop:

```
for (const match of matches('abcdefabcdef', /ab/g)) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Or if you want an array:

```
[ ...matches('abcdefabcdef', /ab/g) ]
```

Comment: Typo: `if (m)` should be `if (match)`

Comment: Arrays are already iterable, so everyone returning an array of matches are also returning iterables. What's better is if you console log an array the browser can actually print out the contents. But console logging a generic iterable just gets you [object Object] { ... }

Comment: All arrays are iterable but not all iterables are arrays. An iterable is superior if you don’t know what the caller will need to do. For example, if you just want the first match an iterable is more efficient.

Comment: your dream is becoming a reality, browsers are rolling out support for [a built-in `matchAll` that returns an iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) :D

Comment: I've come across this answer post-matchAll implementation. I wrote some code for browser JS which supported it, but Node actually did not. This behaves identically to matchAll so I've not had to rewrite stuff - Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Here is my function to get the matches :

```
function getAllMatches(regex, text) {
    if (regex.constructor !== RegExp) {
        throw new Error('not RegExp');
    }

    var res = [];
    var match = null;

    if (regex.global) {
        while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
            res.push(match);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (match = regex.exec(text)) {
            res.push(match);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

// Example:

var regex = /abc|def|ghi/g;
var res = getAllMatches(regex, 'abcdefghi');

res.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item[0]);
});
```

Comment: This solution prevents infinite loops when you forget to add the global flag.

Answer (score 7):

If you're able to use `matchAll` here's a trick:

`Array.From` has a 'selector' parameter so instead of ending up with an array of awkward 'match' results you can project it to what you really need:

```
Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp), m => m[0]);
```

If you have named groups eg. (`/(?<firstname>[a-z][A-Z]+)/g`) you could do this:

```
Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp), m => m.groups.firstName);
```

Comment: the modern way !

Answer (score 4):

Since ES9, there's now a simpler, better way of getting all the matches, together with information about the capture groups, and their index:

```
const string = 'Mice like to dice rice';
const regex = /.ice/gu;
for(const match of string.matchAll(regex)) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

> // ["mice", index: 0, input: "mice like to dice rice", groups:
> undefined]
>
> // ["dice", index: 13, input: "mice like to dice rice",
> groups: undefined]
>
> // ["rice", index: 18, input: "mice like to dice
> rice", groups: undefined]

It is currently supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera. Depending on when you read this, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to see its current support.

Comment: Superb! But it's still important to keep in mind the regex should have a flag `g` and it's `lastIndex` should be reset to 0 before the invocation of `matchAll`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

```
var all_matches = your_string.match(re);
console.log(all_matches)
```

It will return an array of all matches...That would work just fine....
But remember it won't take groups in account..It will just return the full matches...

Comment: regex must have flag `g`, e.g. `/.../g`

Answer (score 0):

I would definatly recommend using the String.match() function, and creating a relevant RegEx for it. My example is with a list of strings, which is often necessary when scanning user inputs for keywords and phrases.

```
    // 1) Define keywords
    var keywords = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

    // 2) Create regex, pass "i" for case-insensitive and "g" for global search
    regex = new RegExp("(" + keywords.join('|') + ")", "ig");
    => /(apple|orange|banana)/gi

    // 3) Match it against any string to get all matches 
    "Test string for ORANGE's or apples were mentioned".match(regex);
    => ["ORANGE", "apple"]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really going to help with your more complex issue but I'm posting this anyway because it is a simple solution for people that aren't doing a global search like you are.

I've simplified the regex in the answer to be clearer (this is not a solution to your exact problem).

```
var re = /^(.+?):"(.+)"$/
var regExResult = re.exec('description:"aoeu"');
var purifiedResult = purify_regex(regExResult);

// We only want the group matches in the array
function purify_regex(reResult){

  // Removes the Regex specific values and clones the array to prevent mutation
  let purifiedArray = [...reResult];

  // Removes the full match value at position 0
  purifiedArray.shift();

  // Returns a pure array without mutating the original regex result
  return purifiedArray;
}

// purifiedResult= ["description", "aoeu"]
```

That looks more verbose than it is because of the comments, this is what it looks like without comments

```
var re = /^(.+?):"(.+)"$/
var regExResult = re.exec('description:"aoeu"');
var purifiedResult = purify_regex(regExResult);

function purify_regex(reResult){
  let purifiedArray = [...reResult];
  purifiedArray.shift();
  return purifiedArray;
}
```

Note that any groups that do not match will be listed in the array as `undefined` values.

This solution uses the ES6 spread operator to purify the array of regex specific values. You will need to run your code through [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) if you want IE11 support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **one line solution without a while loop**.

The order is preserved in the resulting list.

The potential downsides are

1. It clones the regex for every match.
2. The result is in a different form than expected solutions. You'll need to process them one more time.

```
let re = /\s*([^[:]+):\"([^"]+)"/g
let str = '[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]'

(str.match(re) || []).map(e => RegExp(re.source, re.flags).exec(e))
```

```
[ [ 'description:"aoeu"',
    'description',
    'aoeu',
    index: 0,
    input: 'description:"aoeu"',
    groups: undefined ],
  [ ' uuid:"123sth"',
    'uuid',
    '123sth',
    index: 0,
    input: ' uuid:"123sth"',
    groups: undefined ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if there would be edge cases such as extra or missing spaces, this expression with less boundaries might also be an option:

```
^\s*\[\s*([^\s\r\n:]+)\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*([^\s\r\n:]+)\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\]\s*$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gpwikV/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/gpwikV/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^\s*\[\s*([^\s\r\n:]+)\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*([^\s\r\n:]+)\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\]\s*$/gm;
const str = `[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]
[description : "aoeu" uuid: "123sth"]
[ description : "aoeu" uuid: "123sth" ]
 [ description : "aoeu"   uuid : "123sth" ]
 [ description : "aoeu"uuid  : "123sth" ] `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const re = /^\[(?:(.+?):"(.+?)"\s*)+\]$/g
const matches = [...re.exec('[description:"aoeu" uuid:"123sth"]').entries()]
console.log(matches)
```

Basically, this is ES6 way to convert Iterator returned by exec to a regular Array

Answer (score -6):

Here is my answer:

```
var str = '[me nombre es] : My name is. [Yo puedo] is the right word'; 

var reg = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

var a = str.match(reg);

a = a.toString().replace(/[\[\]]/g, "").split(','));
```

Comment: Your input string (`str`) has the wrong format (too much hard brackets). You only capture the key, not the value. Your code has syntax error and and does not execute (the last parentheses). If you answer "old" question with an already acepted answer, make sure you add more knowledge and a better answer then the already accepted one. I dont think your answer does that.