# Simple regular expression issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a beginner in Javascript, and was playing around with regular expressions.

I tried to perform some matching operation but the result is quite confusing.

All what i'm trying to do is to match every website name in :

> "I go to google.com to search, to facebook.com to share and to yahoo.com to send an email."

Here's my code :

```
var text = "I go to google.com to search, to facebook.com to share and to yahoo.com to send an email.";
var pattern = /\w+\.\w+/g;

var matches = pattern.exec(text);

document.write("matches index : " + matches.index + "<br>");
document.write("matches input : " + matches.input + "<br>");
document.write("<br>");
for(i=0 ; i<matches.length ; i++){
    document.write("match number " + i + " : " + matches[i] + "<br>");
}
```

And my result :

> matches index : 0
>
> matches input : i go to google.com to search, to facebook.com to share
>   and to yahoo.com to send an email
>
> match number 0 : google.com

Why does it match *google.com* only, and not the other websites ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "`g`" flag, you can use the `exec` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

So, just execute it multiple times:

```
var match, i = 0;
while(match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    document.write("match number " + (i++) + " : " + match[0] + "<br>");
}
```

or, since you don't have capture groups, use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var matches = text.match(pattern);
for(i=0 ; i<matches.length ; i++){
    document.write("match number " + i + " : " + matches[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, weird though. In [Professional Javascript for web developers](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691/ref=pd_sim_b_1) book. There's an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smokn/gzAVS/) using exec only one time. And the weird thing that it works !

Comment: @Rafael - The example in your fiddle uses capturing groups `( ... )`

Comment: In your last example when there are no matches the for loop will generate an error. So better check if `matches` is not null first.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that the replace method is sometimes a better fit to iterate through a string, even if you don't actually intend to replace anything.

Here is how it could work in your case:

```
var matches = text.replace(pattern,function($0){alert($0);});
```

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WnfgS/)