# Regex extracting multiple matches for string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an issue with writing my regex
For some reason it always returns same match instead of multiple

I am trying to isolate the Client information starting with "Client Full Name" and finishing when new "Client Full Name" starts or is end of string

My regex so far is:

```
((?:Client Full Name)([\s\S]*)?Client Full Name)*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zQo0ziVqLcYlYshi)

If you solve that, please write down the explanation for me so I do learn

Comment: Have you used `g` flag

Comment: nope.. not sure how to use that

Comment: See also [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript).

Comment: var patt = /((?:Client Full Name)([\s\S]*)?Client Full Name)*/g;

Comment: In any case, even by using /g, you still will match only the first client in your case, because the second one doesn't end with \n\nClient Full Name.