# JavaScript find if string has a substring that matches a given reg exp

Tags: javascript, string

```
var str = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM - John Doe: How is everything going on? Check this: iPhone7!"
```

I want to check if string contains a substring that matches  `AM - <some-name>:`. For eg, in above string it should match `AM - John Doe:` and return `John Doe`. (of course once it matches, I can get the name using substring). Also, Sometimes there maybe special characters instead of white spaces in `AM - John Doe:`. Regular expression should work in this case also.

eg:

```
var str1 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM - John Doe likes your photo";
var str2 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe replied to your comment";
var str3 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe: Whats going on";
var str4 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe: Whats going on : hmmm";
```

The regular expression should match **str3** and **str4** since it contains a sub-string that begins with ***AM*** and ends with the first ***:***

For both str3 and str4, I want to get the name John Doe.
Note: str1 and str2 has John Doe too but there it does not immediately trail by **:**

Expressions I have tried:

```
str.match(/[AP]M - \w+[ ]?\w+[ ]?\w+:./);
```

Above fails when there are special characters such as UTF-8 characters. It is not visible but there seems to be characters such as e2 80 80.

Comment: What kind of special characters can there be?

Comment: Please provide examples of valid matches and invalid strings.

Comment: See this question: [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: If you use a negated character class it will match any chars but the one inside the class. I guess it fits your case.

Comment: The symbol you mentioned in the question is `U+2000, EN QUAD`. Acc. to MDN, `\s` matches [*`[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). I think `/\b[AP]M\s+(?:-\s+)?([^:]+):/` should work for you. If not, try the one I currently have in the answer.

Comment: I would also ask for you to provide either a list of valid and invalid chars concerning the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`/\b[AP]M\W+(?:-\W+)?([^:]+):/`](https://regex101.com/r/pX4bW4/3)

```js
var str1 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM - John Doe likes your photo";
var str2 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe replied to your comment";
var str3 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe: Whats going on";
var str4 = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM John Doe: Whats going on : hmmm";
var ss = [ str1, str2, str3, str4 ]; // Test strings
var rx = /\b[AP]M\W+(?:-\W+)?([^:]+):/; 
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + ((m = ss[s].match(rx)) ? m[1] : "NONE") + "</b><br/>";
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[AP]M` - `AM` or `PM`
- `\W+`  - 1+ non-word chars
- `(?:-\W+)?` - optional sequence of a hyphen and a non-word char
- `([^:]+)` - Group 1 (our output) capturing one or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon.

Since `[^...]` is a *negated character class* it will match *any* characters up to the first `:` (excluding that `:` from the match), but the trailing `:` in the pattern will actually *require* the presence of `:` in the string.

Comment: Awesome. I have been trying for hours. This works! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Actually nope. It failed for str1. It matched str1 which it should not have as str1 does not have any trailing ":"

Comment: So, what is your pattern now? Match all the uppercased words after `"AM/PM - "`? Can there be Unicode letters, like in `Сергей Макаров`?

Comment: var str = "4/16/14, 10:24 AM - John Doe How is everything going on? Check this iPhone7!"

Above exp matches this str. It should not since there is no trailing ":" after Doe

Comment: The symbol you mentioned in the question is `U+2000, EN QUAD`. Acc. to MDN, `\s` matches [*`[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). I think `/\b[AP]M\s+(?:-\s+)?([^:]+):/` should work for you. If not, try the one I currently have in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example with your regex that catches special chars which you can find [here](https://regex101.com/r/fL0iG5/4)

As i said im using your regex by modifying it as such:

```
[AP]M[^a-zA-Z]-[^a-zA-Z]\w+[ ]?\w+[ ]?\w+:.
```

if you would like to also exclude digits you can modify it as such:

```
[AP]M[^a-zA-Z\d]-[^a-zA-Z\d]\w+[ ]?\w+[ ]?\w+:.
```

Also if you are expecting special characters in the name you can use `\S` instead of `\w`, this will include everything but white space chars.
Then the regex will be as such:

```
[AP]M[^a-zA-Z]-[^a-zA-Z]\S+[ ]?\S+[ ]?\S+:.
```

i have updated the Regex101 example.

Comment: This blacklisting approach is somewhat fragile. If there are spaces around `-`, the `[^a-zA-Z\d]` are not helpful since `\s` is quite enough. When it comes to `\w`, what if the name is `Łukasz Sącz`? It won't match then.

Comment: I would like to prove you wrong on that. First of all \s is not enough since the question is stated that `" Also, Sometimes there maybe special characters instead of white spaces in AM - John Doe:. Regular expression should work in this case also."`. Therefore \s is not enough at all.
Also if you use [\S ] instead you will also catch any a-z chars. The point of the whole regex is to catch the special chars and white space around  `-`.