# Javascript - extract all element attributes by regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, attributes

I have common meta tags like that:
`<meta id="1" name="keywords" content="some keywords" />`

My APP is writen in NodeJs and I need to extract all attributes like that:

```
[
 id: "1",
 name: "keywords",
 content: "some keywords",
]
```

I have folowing regex:

```
var attrsRegex = new RegExp(/\s(.*?)=["'](.*?)["']/gi);
var attrs = attrsRegex.exec('<meta name="author" content="Alza a.s." />');
console.log(attrs);
```

The code return only the first attribute:

`[" id="1"", "id", "1", index: 5, input: "<meta id="1" name="keywords" content="some keywords" />"]`

It seems the `G` flag doesnt work.?

[JsFiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3t593g34/2/)

Comment: `/g` only advances the RegExp lastIndex, you need to call the `exec()` inside a loop to get all the matches.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can you give me some example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6323598/3832970 - http://jsfiddle.net/7yS2V/

Comment: Thnak you, it helps me.