# Regex: Filter particular Pattern JAVASCRIPT/angular

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to filter a repetitive pattern inside a string. The string is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo >ligula eget dolor >>(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ### >3.4039###verified),(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ### >3.4039###verified)  and so on......

The pattern is

> (text:text###text###text###text###text),(text:text###text###text###text###text) and so on......

I need to extract all of the data in a structural form (Better JSON ).
If anybody can help me?

I am trying this stuff and it only returns a single match.

```
var txt='(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ###3.4039###verified),(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ###3.4039###verified)';

  var re1='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re2='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)';    // Uninteresting: word
  var re3='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re4='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';  // Word 1
  var re5='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re6='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';  // Word 2
  var re7='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re8='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';  // Word 3
  var re9='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re10='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])';  // Float 1
  var re11='.*?';   // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re12='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; // Word 4



  var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,["i"]);
  var m = p.exec(txt);

  if (m != null)
  {
      var word1=m[1];
      var word2=m[2];
      var word3=m[3];
      var float1=m[4];
      var word4=m[5];
      document.write("("+word1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word3.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+float1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word4.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
  }
```

Comment: A duplicate of [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `exec` returns a **single** match and all of its capture groups. To get all the matches, you must call `exec` multiple times until it finally returns null.

Your code can be changed to

```js
var text = '(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ###3.4039###verified),(Special:Loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar###loremipsumdollar ###3.59###verified)';

var regEx = /.*?(?:\w+).*?((?:\w+)).*?((?:\w+)).*?((?:\w+)).*?([+-]?\d*\.\d+).*?((?:\w+))/g;

var result, allMatches = [];
while ((result = regEx.exec(text)) != null) {

  // Get all the matches in a variable
  var item = {};
  for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    item['word' + i] = result[i];
  }

  allMatches.push(item);

}

console.log(allMatches);
```

More over yor regular expression can be modified by using the `word` selector by using `\w`