# Regex - get multiple result from same line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am reading in a file line by line in js and looking for any string within quotes, as follows:

```
// regex to find all strings within double-quotes
var re = new RegExp("\"([^\"]*)\"");

// parse each line in inFile
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(inFile)
});

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    var res = line.match(re)
    // do something else here
});
```

This works great if there is only one string on each line within quotes. How can I adapt it to iterate over multiple matches on the same line?

Thanks

Comment: `g` - global flag: `/.../g`

Comment: Use `var re = /"([^"]*)"/g;`. If you want leading/trailing `"`, you do not even need the parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, sounds simple but im confused and getting errors ha! i dont want the leading/trailing quotes...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript how to access all captured values. If you cannot use a regex literal, use `var re = new RegExp("\"([^\"]*)\"", "g");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah ok, so i think my issues are from being able to iterate the results, thanks for the pointers.