# Extract all hashtags from string without #

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I'm extracting hashtags from strings like this:

```
const mystring = 'huehue #arebaba,saas #ole #cool asdsad #aaa';
const hashtags = mystring.match(/#\w+/g) || [];
console.log(hashtags);
```

The output is:

```
['#arebaba', '#ole', '#cool', '#aaa']
```

How my regex should be so that the match is:

```
['arebaba', 'ole', 'cool', 'aaa']
```

I don't want to use map function!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: Read about regex capture groups. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 6):

```js
const mystring = 'huehue #arebaba,saas #ole #cool asdsad #aaa';
var regexp = /#(\w+)/g;
var match = regexp.exec(mystring);
while (match != null){
  console.log(match[1])
  match = regexp.exec(mystring)
}
```

EDIT The code can be shortened. However, it's not your regex that will solve your problem, but picking the correct method.

```js
var mystring = 'huehue #arebaba,saas #ole #cool asdsad #aaa',
    match;
var regexp = /#(\w+)/g;    
while (match = regexp.exec(mystring))
  console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: This do the trick, but I'm not sure how to adapt to my use case. My 2 lines code became 7 in your example. I just need to change my regex, but not sure what should be.

Comment: Using prototype by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

You already matched multiple substrings and you know there is `#` in front, so just remove it:

```js
const mystring = 'huehue #arebaba,saas #ole #cool asdsad #aaa';
const hashtags = mystring.match(/#\w+/g).map(x => x.substr(1)) || [];
console.log(hashtags);
```

Comment: Specified in the question: I don't want to use map function.

Comment: @mlambrichs Yeah, but this is not for OP, but for those who would like to use it. This answer is a community wiki answer. A requirement not to use `.map` is "artificial", sounds like some school assignment, not a real life one.

Comment: I'm currently doing with map, but I want to skip this step and extract de hashtags already without #.

Comment: @IbnClaudius. You did not post your code with `map`. Thus, the answer is here just in case other users want to use it. It is a **community wiki** answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Positive Lookbehind** option:

> `(?<=...)`
> Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume any characters.

For example given the string 'foobar', the regex `(?<=foo)bar` would match `bar` only.

Or in this case (crating an array of word tags):

```js
const mystring = 'huehue #arebaba,saas #ole #cool asdsad #aaa';
const hashtags = mystring.match(/(?<=#)\w+/g) || [];
// ["arebaba","ole","cool","aaa"];
```