# Cannot get regex to be greedy in matches for items in brackets []

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this input:

> [[00], [01], [02], [03]]

I'm trying to extract all the values inside the [ ].

The regex I've crafted looks like this `/[^[\]]+(?=])/g`
But if I try in on my input, it only returns the first element

> $ /[^[\]]+(?=])/g.exec(' [[00], [01], [02], [03]]');
>
> $ [ '00', index: 3, input: ' [[00], [01], [02], [03]]' ]

What I don't understand is I've built the regex and tested it on https://regex101.com/r/QhZDMR/1, and on there it seems to return all the values just fine.

Comment: You have different regexes in the question and the regex demo.

Comment: Getting multiple matches with a JS regex is a long solved problem, see the linked dupe reason.

Comment: Fixed the mismatch, SO had removed my escaped `\\`. @Ec_ actually provided the answer I was looking for.

Comment: It is [already there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622095/3832970), no need providing it again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec function finds only the first match. Instead use match like this:

```
"[[00], [01], [02], [03]]".match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know this. Need more rep to upvote :)