# regex to return all image tags from string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have been working on this for a bit with no success. hope someone has the knowledge i have been looking for.

i have a string that i cant modify from which i need to get all the  tags stored in an array.

```
the string looks like this :

    <p><strong>BLA BLA BLA</strong></p>

<p><strong>BLA BLA BLA</p>

<p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut mauris vulputate, pellentesque eros sit amet, consequat quam. Nam tempor ipsum ac ligula aliquam, vel dictum elit feugiat. Vivamus vehicula dolor quis ligula malesuada gravida. Curabitur suscipit ante ut sodales sodales. Donec mattis odio a sodales iaculis. Integer urna augue, convallis non euismod a, facilisis vel ex. Nulla sed sodales felis, ac semper odio. Maecenas malesuada justo ac porta faucibus. Aliquam tempor justo ut egestas bibendum.</em></p>
<img alt="lorem ipsum" data-caption="enter caption here" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="901b744e-a279-4271-9e96-f0836fed3e76" src="https://www.blablabla.com/image.png" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img alt="lorem ipsum" data-caption="enter caption here" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="901b744e-a279-4271-9e96-f0836fed3e76" src="https://www.blablabla.com/image.png" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

i was trying with a couple of Regex but they fail to return all the image tags, they return the first one or none at all.

```
.match('<img.*');
.match('<img\ssrc\s*=\s*"(.+?)\/>');
```

does anyone know what can i do?

thank you.

Comment: That is not a regular expression.... That is a string

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use a reg exp and not just use DOM parsing?

Comment: `.match` is only going to return one result. You need to call `.exec` in a loop to find all matches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript

Comment: @Andrew: match can return an array of all results, if you specify 'global' flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using regex to parse HTML but since this is a case of img tag which can't be nested, hence in this scope only you can use this regex. Pick the url from group 1

```
<img.*?\s+src=['"]?(.*)['"]?.*?\/>
```

Check here,

https://regex101.com/r/qAf16A/3

Comment: using this regex and the global flag fixed my issue.

Comment: Pleased to know it helped you :)