# How I can create javascript regexp to get matches {{match}}

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to create JavaScript regexp that get all matches

```
  {{match1}}{{match2}} notmatch {{match3}}
```

result will be

```
['{{match1}}','{{match2}}','{{match3}}']
```

what i tried so far

```
 var text='{{match1}}{{match2}} notmatch {{match3}}';
 const regex = /(?<=\{{)(.*?)(?=\}})/gm;
 var match = text.match(regex);
```

this is working fine with chrome but in Firefox, IE and edge i am getting this error

```
SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier
```

any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a more simplified regex like the following:
(Not sure about IE, but it should work for Chrome and Firefox.)

```js
var text='{{match1}}{{match2}} notmatch {{match3}}';
const regex = /{{([^}]+)}}/gm;
var match = text.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

**Without the braces**: (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)), ([Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084915/how-i-can-create-javascript-regexp-to-get-matches-between-match/55085138?noredirect=1#comment96915586_55085138)'s suggestion).

```js
var text='{{match1}}{{match2}} notmatch {{match3}}';
var regex = /{{([^}]+)}}/gm;
var matches;
while (matches = regex.exec(text)){
    console.log(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to include the braces in the match result. That's why he's using lookarounds.

Comment: i thought i cant get it with the braces but now its done, i will update the question so others might find it useful thanks ABm Ruman for the answer. and Barmar thanks for spreading frustration

Comment: ooh, I  thought you need to get rid of the braces. Guess I'll have to revert my changes too :)