# How to split string of meta tags using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have multiple meta tags in a string and i want to be able to split them into an array.

sample data: `"<meta ..... /><meta ..... /><meta ..... /><meta ..... />"`

What is the best way to do this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using regex to parse HTML, but if you're doing something quick & dirty which will not go to production: `"<meta ..... /><meta ..... /><meta ..... /><meta ..... />".replace(/></gi, ">,<").split(",")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var str="<meta test1 /><meta test2 /><meta test3 /><meta test4 />";
    var patt = /<meta (.*?)\/>/gm;
    var arr=str.match(patt);
    var i = 0;
    for(item of arr){
     arr[i]=item.substring(5,item.length-2);
     i++;
    }
  console.log(arr);
```