# Javascript regex parse complex url string

Tags: javascript, regex, url, string-parsing, query-string

I need to parse a complex URL string to fetch specific values.

From the following URL string:

`/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss`

I need to extract this result in array format:

```
['http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss', 'http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss']
```

I tried already with this one `/url=([^&]+)/` but I can't capture all correctly all the query parameters. And I would like to omit the `url=`.

[RegExr link](https://regexr.com/4rvkc)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *And I would like to omit the `url=`* - you already omit it since it is not part of the capturing group. Your data is inside Group 1. I think you need `var regex = /url=(.+?)(?=&url=|$)/g`, run `regex.exec(str)` [in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417) and get Group 1.

Comment: You are using a capturing group and that is where the value is. Try `url=(.*?)(?=&url=|$))` https://regex101.com/r/snM42Q/1

Comment: Did you consider to use a query string parsing lib instead of doing this with a regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex works for me: `url=([a-z:/.?=-]+&[a-z=]+)`

also, you can test this: `/http(s)?://([a-z-.?=&])+&/g`

[image: Example]

```js
const string = '/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url.com?filter=latest&format=rss'

const string2 = '/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url.com?filter=hot&format=rss&next=parm&url=http://any-feed-url.com?filter=latest&format=rss'

const regex = /url=([a-z:/.?=-]+&[a-z=]+)/g;
const regex2 = /http(s)?:\/\/([a-z-.?=&])+&/g;

console.log(string.match(regex))
console.log(string2.match(regex2))
```

Comment: Hi Kordrad, thank you. It works but do you know how to omit ```url=``` in the results? Of course, I can do a string replace. But exist some way to ignore it with a similar regex?

Comment: `[^url]+` probably doesn’t do what you intended. `((?!url=).)+`, maybe?

Comment: try this: `/http(s)?://([a-z-.?=&])+&/g`, just start search your value from `http` text

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `split` method ? instead of using regex.

```
const urlsArr = "/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss".split("url=");
    urlsArr.shift(); // removing first item from array -> "/api/rss/feeds?"
console.log(urlsArr)
```

)

which is going to return `["/api/rss/feeds?", "http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&", "http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss"]` then i am dropping first item in array

if possible its better to use something else then regex [CoddingHorror: regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

You can matchAll the url's, then map the capture group 1 to an array.

```js
str = '/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss'

arr = [...str.matchAll(/url=(.*?)(?=&url=|$)/g)].map(x => x[1])

console.log(arr)
```

But `matchAll` isn't supported by older browsers.
But looping an `exec` to fill an array works also.

```js
str = '/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss'

re = /url=(.*?)(?=&url=|$)/g;
arr = [];
while (m = re.exec(str)) { 
arr.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your input is better-formed in reality than shown in the question and you’re targeting a modern JavaScript environment, there’s `URL`/`URLSearchParams`:

```js
const input = '/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot%26format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising%26format=rss';
const url = new URL(input, 'http://example.com/');

console.log(url.searchParams.getAll('url'));
```

Notice how `&` has to be escaped as `%26` for it to make sense.

Without this input in a standard form, it’s not clear which rules of URLs are still on the table.

Comment: You are not using the string in question, which is `/api/rss/feeds?url=http://any-feed-url-a.com?filter=hot&format=rss&url=http://any-feed-url-b.com?filter=rising&format=rss`, so this answer does not help OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You don’t know that it doesn’t help the OP.

Comment: It cannot since you are not answering the current question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Not true, sorry.

Comment: If this helps, there is no need to duplicate already existing solutions. The question will be a duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/)