# How to use Regex in below example?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Regular expression in the validation while I am trying to match the string with giving pattern, the result is not as expected

Pattern: `(?:[0-9])*21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})`

Expected result: I do not want to capture the letters or number until it matches 21, which  means

Example: I have a string, In this string, I do not want to capture the number and letter which is before `21` i.e I don't want to capture `Aabcde12345` and the expected result should be `345621822`
But, the result what I am getting is just `822` because in the number `345621822` 21 will reoccur and gives me the result `822` which is wrong

can someone please help me

Note: Also Please help me to update start over Question according to it `

```js
const text = "Aabcde1234521345621822";
const regex = "(?:[0-9])*21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})";
const result = text.match(regex);

console.log(result);

// expected output: Array [""1234521345621822"", "345621822"]
```

`

Comment: Does it solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/regex-to-extract-all-matches-from-string-using-regexp-exec

Comment: Any other solution would be accepted or you want to solve it only with Regex?

Comment: @CarlosSaizOrteu 
can you please help me with below question, this is what I wanted to solution 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102152/how-to-capture-reoccurring-digit-by-using-regex-in-below-example

Comment: @Zain Ul Abideen can you please help me with below question, this is what I wanted to solution 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102152/how-to-capture-reoccurring-digit-by-using-regex-in-below-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the capture group from the first part (the brackets)
and add the ? to make the first digits as non-greedy

`[0-9]*?21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})`

Comment: @Vikas If this answer solved your problem, please mark it accordingly :) Thank you!

Comment: this is working for this example, Marked it. 
can you please help me with below question, this is what I wanted to solution 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102152/how-to-capture-reoccurring-digit-by-using-regex-in-below-example