# How to capture reoccurring digit by using REGEX in below example

Tags: javascript, regex

We are just using simple JavaScript .match() by using REGEX, I have a problem with matching the below `REGEX pattern`.

After scanning the below QR code I am trying to match the serial number which is `682321973` by using the below `REGEX`
`(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-])|(?:\u001d))*21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})\u001d.*$)|(?:S?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,18}))`

The reason for using this BIG regex is because `SERIAL` number starts after (21) in below image `(21) 682321973` 
So we will ignore or we will not capture the number or letters parts before (21), once it matches `(21)` we will capture the remaining number i.e `682321973` 
But the problem is the BELOW regex is not matching because there is a reoccurrence of number 21 in serial number `682321973` The result is `973` 
 But the strange thing is in serial number if there is a `22` i.e `682322973`instead of `682321973` then we get the correct result i.e `682322973`

When we scan the below QR code, 
the text we get is : `"\u001d010405686902130021682321973\u001d24011020250\u001d422276"`(without quotes)

Snippet which I am getting the wrong result for serial number `682321973`
Note: In the below result we are taking Index 1 as a result

```js
const string = "\u001d010405686902130021682321973\u001d24011020250\u001d422276";
const regex = "(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-])|(?:\u001d))*21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})\u001d.*$)|(?:S?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,18}))";
const result = string.match(regex);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["12344", "682321973"]
```

Snippet which I am getting the correct result for serial number `682322973`

```js
const string = "\u001d010405686902130021682322973\u001d24011020250\u001d422276";
    const regex = "(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-])|(?:\u001d))*21([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15})\u001d.*$)|(?:S?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,18}))";
    const result = string.match(regex);

    console.log(result);
    // expected output: Array ["12344", "682322973"]
```

So can someone please help me if the number re-occur in the serial number `682321973` i need this to capture `682321973` instead of just `973`

[image: GS1 DATA Matrix]

For Reference Below attached one more, just to show serial number always starts with (21) 
, [image: Another Bar code image]

Comment: Is the serial number you want always followed by the character `\u001d`? Does the serial number have a known, fixed number of digits? Are the two characters that precede the serial number (e.g., `21`) fixed and known?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Serial number might have upto 1 to 18 digits , yes , The serial number always precedes with `21` i have attached one more screenshot, where you can see serial number always starts after (21), basically `(21)`, is an identification number which just tell us what ever comes after (21) is serial number <br> Is the serial number you want always followed by the character \u001d - Yes

Comment: That is important and essential information, but it seems that you are telling us that the beginning of a serial number is ambiguous if the string contains two or more instances of `21`. In `"\u001d010405686902130021682321973\u001d"` what, if anything, do you know about `0104056869021300`? In particular, does that substring always contain 16 characters? When responding to comments asking for clarification you should edit your question rather that elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 0):

The string

```
\u001d010405686902130021682321973\u001d24011020250\u001d422276
```

is seen to have 3 parts:

```
\u001d010405686902130021682321973
\u001d24011020250
\u001d422276
```

which in this case have different lengths.

Here the serial number is contained in the first of these (though that is not evident from the data). That string can be viewed as having four parts, which may be obtained in three possible ways:

```
\u001d 01040568690 21 30021682321973
\u001d 0104056869021300 21 682321973
\u001d 0104056869021300216823 21 973
```

The associated serial numbers are `30021682321973`, `682321973` and `873`. Though we have been told that `682321973` is the actual serial number here, as serial numbers have between 1 and 18 digits, all of these potentially give the correct value.

The only way to determine which, if any of these serial numbers is correct lies in the second group of digits:

```
01040568690             (11 digits)
0104056869021300        (16 digits)
0104056869021300216823  (22 digits)
```

If that group always contains 16 digits (as it does in the two examples given), we can extract serial numbers with the regular expression

```
(?<=\\u\d{3}d\d{16}21)\d+(?=\\u\d{3}d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6wp2d/2/)

Javascript's regex engine does not recognize Unicode characters. Therefore, `\u001d` is treated as a backslash followed by the letter `u`,  followed by the digits `001` followed by the letter `d`.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=      # begin positive lookbehind
  \\      # match '\'
  u       # match 'u'
  \d{3}   # match 3 digits (or replace with '001' if appropriate)
  d       # match 'd'
  \d{16}  # match 16 digits
  21      # match '21'
)         # end positive lookbehind  
\d+       # match 1+ digits (serial number) 
(?=       # begin positive lookahead
  \\      # match '\'
  u       # match 'u'
  \d{3}   # match 3 digits (or replace with '001' if appropriate)
  d       # match 'd'
)         # end positive lookahead
```

If the part of the string between `\u001d` and the `21` that immediately precedes the serial number is not always 16 digits, the only remaining way to reliably extract the serial number is to break that part of the string down into its component elements, but we have have not been told what those components are.

Comment: Thank you ..This works.. and can you please help me to understand the above two snippets, In the second snippet, the serial number is `682322973` and after it matches `21` which is exactly before `68`, it gets printed but the `21` also present in 1040568690**21**300 , but it did not capture the `21` which is behind `300`, Like no matter how many 21 you write before 300 or instead of 300 `32102107` (snippet 2), it will always starts with 68.

Comment: You are correct. I have assumed the serial number begins with the 24th character after a backslash. `\u001d` is viewed as 6 characters by the regex (because it does not support Unicode), then the sixteen characters `0104056869021300`, then the two characters `21`: `6+16+2 = 24`. As I said in the answer, this only works if there are always exactly 16 characters between `\u001d` and the string `21` that immediately precedes the serial number. I don't know if that is true. That's for you to determine.