# How can i get the units with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this regex to get the unit, but i only can get an unit (8.5 lb), i want to get everything (8.5 lb, 25.4 lb)

```js
let data=`<br><span style="font-size: 15px;"><span style="color: #000000;">• 8.5 lb, 25.4 lb</ `

const regex = / \s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:l[ lb ]|lb))?)\b/g;
let m = regex.exec(data)
console.log(m)
```

Comment: @Nicolas in this moment i get only (8.5 lb) i wan to get (8.5 lb, 25.4 lb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx to extract all matches from string using RegExp.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/regex-to-extract-all-matches-from-string-using-regexp-exec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` returns just the first match. Call it repeatedly to get all matches. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Alternatively, use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Regular Expression

The following regular expression matches 1 or more groups of (decimal number followed by character words):

```regex
/([0-9\.]+\s+\w+)/g
```

- `[0-9\.]+`: matches a sequence consisting of one or more of the following: numbers, the literal
  "`.`" character
- `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` one or more times
- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `(...)` groups the entire above match
- `g modifier`: returns all matches (don't return after first match)

#### The JavaScript

as @DougDomeny said,

> [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns the first match. Call it repeatedly to get all matches.

You can use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `exec`. `String.prototype.match()` returns:

> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (`g`) flag, or null if no matches are found.
>
> - If the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.
> - If the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. In this case, the returned item will have additional properties as described below.

```js
const regex = /([0-9\.]+\s+\w+)/g;
const m = data.match(regex)
console.log(m)
```

#### Result:

```
> ["8.5 lb", "25.4 lb"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could alter your regex to match the comma as well, and repeat your capture group for one or multiple time.

```
  \s*(( )?[0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:l[ lb ]|lb))?(, )?)+\b
```

Here, I've added `(, )?` and repeated the regex one or multiple time.

I've also added  `( )?` so your cases can start with a space.

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZvFWf4/1)

Comment: i get an array [
  " 8.5lb, 25.4 lb",
  "25.4 lb",
  undefined,
  undefined
]