# Get text between characters multiple time JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
inputStr = 'Hi My Name is ~Satish~ L ~Rathore~ , I live in ~Navi Mumbai~.'
```

Output Should be like each matching text between `'~'`

`'Satish'`
`'Rathore'`
`'Navi Mumbai'`

Comment: should be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/regex-to-extract-all-matches-from-string-using-regexp-exec

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using Regular expression as:

```
/~[\w\s]+~/g
```

[image]

```js
const inputStr =
  'Hi My Name is ~Satish~ L ~Rathore~ , I live in ~Navi Mumbai~.';

const result = inputStr
  .match(/~[\w\s]+~/g)
  .map((s) => s.slice(1, s.length - 1));

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do as:

```
/~[^~]+~/g
```

[image]

```js
const inputStr =
  'Hi My Name is ~Satish~ L ~Rathore~ , I live in ~Navi Mumbai~.';

const result = inputStr.match(/~[^~]+~/g).map((s) => s.slice(1, s.length - 1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works exactly. like I want ..