# From an HTML string with comments like `<!-- paragraph {"className":"123"} -->` extract only the characters after `className`

Tags: javascript

There is a string like this

```js
var string =
`<!-- paragraph {"className":"123"} -->
<p>abc</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"456"} -->
<p>cde</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"789"} -->
<p>fgh</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->`
 
const regex = /"className":"(.+)"/g;

string = string.replace(regex, "");
console.log(string);
```

I want to delete all characters except those following the `className`.

In other words, I want to make it look like `123456789` in the end.

If you can tell me a better way, I would appreciate your advice.

Any method other than `replace` is fine.

Comment: `.replace(/\D/gm, "")`? Or could there be digits elsewhere that you don't want to keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match` then `replace` the string you don't want

```js
var string =
`<!-- paragraph {"className":"123"} -->
<p>abc</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"456"} -->
<p>cde</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"789"} -->
<p>fgh</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->`
 
const regex = /"className":"(.+)"/g;
let arr = string.match(regex, '');
arr = arr.map(e => e.replace(`"className":"`, '').slice(0, -1))
let str = arr.join('')
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.+` is a [greedy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers#greedy_versus_non-greedy) pattern and you only rely on `.` not matching a linebreak (without the [`s` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll)).
This might not be robust.

Your string is an HTML string, so [using an HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4642212) is a more appropriate start, using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
Since HTML comments can be placed anywhere in HTML, the HTML parser will place these contents automatically in different places; wrap the string in a `<body>`…`</body>` to make sure everything is placed in one consistent spot.
You can later access the contents by `.body.childNodes`.

Next, use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the list of Nodes into a proper Array and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it

- by [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) to get only the HTML comment nodes (using the static properties on `Node`), and
- by [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get only those comments starting with `paragraph` and not those starting with `/paragraph` (using [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) and [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)).

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the resulting comment nodes to get their text contents.

Now it’s a bit unclear what the format is.
Is it always one word (with no spaces), followed by a single space, followed by the `{`…`}` structure?
Can there be multiple `{`…`}` structures?
Can there be something after the `{`…`}` structure?
You’ll have to figure this out for yourself and refine any regex, but I’m going to assume that the `paragraph`…`/paragraph` thing is analogous to HTML tags, which would mean that the *first* space is followed by the `{`…`}` structure.
However, I’m *not* going to assume that these `{"className":"123"}` structures are always going to be free of spaces.

Splitting only by the first space, discarding the text before, and keeping the rest can be achieved by splitting by all spaces, taking everything from index 1, and merging everything by a space again: `.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")`.

The intermediate result is:

```js
[
  "{\"className\":\"123\"}",
  "{\"className\":\"456\"}",
  "{\"className\":\"789\"}"
]
```

These are JSON strings.
Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (in the existing `map`) to parse everything and [access the `className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Now you have this inermediate result:

```js
[
  "123",
  "456",
  "789"
]
```

Joining it all with `.join("")` results in the desired `"123456789"` string.

### Full code

```js
const string =
`<!-- paragraph {"className":"123"} -->
<p>abc</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"456"} -->
<p>cde</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"789"} -->
<p>fgh</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->`,
  result = Array.from(new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<body>${string}</body>`, "text/html")
    .body
    .childNodes)
      .filter(({ nodeType, textContent }) => nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE && textContent.trim().startsWith("paragraph"))
      .map(({ textContent }) => JSON.parse(textContent.trim()
        .split(" ")
        .slice(1)
        .join(" "))
          .className)
            .join("");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

##### What you have tried is replacing,while you have to try to "find" a match

Two examples are given below
What i have gave below looks just like your question,
You have tried `string.replace(regex);`,
but answer is `string.replace(regex,function(match, g1, g2) {/*...*/});`

```js
var string =
`<!-- paragraph {"className":"123"} -->
<p>abc</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"456"} -->
<p>cde</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->
 
<!-- paragraph {"className":"789"} -->
<p>fgh</p>
<!-- /paragraph -->`
 
const regex = /"className":"(.+)"/g;


var answer="";
var answerArray=[];
string.replace(regex, function(match, g1, g2) { 
/*
use g1 variable for anything 
like array or string,two examples are given below...
*/
answer+=g1;
answerArray.push(g1);
});
console.log(answer);
console.log(answerArray);
```

###### [Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443943/14862885)